# java.util.Locale making Country LowerCase

Tags: java, locale

I am setting

```
java.util.Locale localeWithoutCountryCode = new Locale("fr_FR");
```

But when I retrieve its value, it returns me `"fr_fr"` ( Lowercase country) and this is causing my message lookups to fail.
I want it to keep the country case as is.

Answer (score 2):

The single-argument constructor for `Locale` takes exactly an ISO language as its parameter; you're passing in a language and variant. Use `new Locale("fr", "FR")` instead.

If this is hard-coded for some reason, you can just use `Locale.FRANCE`.

Comment: I hate the splitting method , but looks like i need to do that. Thanks.