# How to convert String into locale in java

Tags: java, string, locale

I need to convert a given string into locale. String has value "fr_US" and I need to convert it into locale (in java.util.locale).

I found one method in "org.apache.commons.lang.LocaleUtils" that does the conversion but I am looking for a method that converts into "java.util.locale"

```
String val = "fr_US";
locale l1 = LocaleUtils.toLocale(val);
// this converts into org.apache.commons.lang.LocaleUtils
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435143/java-util-locale-making-country-lowercase

Comment: Have you tried to look into the `java.util.Locale` class ? Maybe something like `getInstance` ?

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
String val = "fr_US";
String[] tab = val.split("_");
Locale locale = new Locale(tab[0], tab[1]);
```

Or, if you hardcoded you val

```
Locale locale = new Locale("fr", "US");
```

Also in `Locale` we have a method `forLanguageTag` but as parameter you have to pass BCP 47 language tag (with `-`, not `_`).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the apache tool so the right way is:

```
Locale myLocale =  LocaleUtils.toLocale("fr_US");
```

that is the same as

```
Locale myLocale = new Locale("fr", "US");
```